# Is there an efficient way you can draw graceful tree for $n$ points and $n-1$ edges by hand?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So I recently found this conjucture called the 'graceful tree problem'. And I think it deals with this. Some species of this has been solved (the butterfly and the chain). So if I have $n=20$ and I need to draw a graceful labelling with that by hand. So is there any known trick or method in doing so?
I'm actually very new to this, so I really don't know any of the technical terms, but still curious to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a *star* would do, ie one vertex in middle labelled as 0, and $n$ vertices only connecting to it labelled from $1$ to $n$